# Allowing cell to overflow without affecting indentation

Tags: tables, indentation

I wish to allow a specific table cell to overflow horizontally without affecting indentation of the column that the overflowing cell reaches into. How can this be achieved? Google/Stackoverflow isn't offering up much, but it might be due to my lack of good ways to word this problem concisely.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you give an approximate graphic representation of what you need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 \makebox[0pt][l]{very wide stufffffff}
```

takes up no space and over (or actualy under) prints anything to the right of it
so you can put such a construction in one table cell without affecting the width of that column.

Comment: Wonderful formatting trick, works great!