# Allow cell content to overflow to next columns

Tags: tables, tabularx, overflow

I want to recreate such a format in latex:

[image: desired format, a three column table]

so far, I've came up with this

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
@{} p{.2\textwidth}
@{} X @{}
{\raggedleft\arraybackslash} p{.1\textwidth} @{}
}

\small{Sep 2022 - Jan 2023} &
\large\textbf{Teaching Assistant, Cloud Computing} \vspace{2mm}\newline\vspace{2mm}\normalsize
Under the supervision of Dr. Random.
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3in]
       \item Did this super important thing Did this super important thing Did this super important thing Did this super important thing 
      \item Worked on that research paper          
\end{itemize}
\hfill \normalsize &
\small{Random Univ. of Tech.} \\

\small{Sep 2018 - Feb 2023} &
    \large\textbf{Teaching Assistant, Machine Learning} \vspace{2mm}\newline\vspace{2mm}\normalsize Under the supervision of Dr. Random
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3in]
           \item Did this super important thing
          \item Worked on that research paper          
    \end{itemize}
    \hfill \normalsize
& \small{Random Univ. of Tech.} \\
\end{tabularx}
```

which gives me this:

[image: my current 3 column table, which is different]
The problem with my code is that the second column text is wrapped when reaching 3rd column. I want the text to be wrapped at the end of the table width, i.e. i want it to overflow on the 3rd column.

I've already checked this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179692/allowing-cell-to-overflow-without-affecting-indentation), the `makebox` solution proposed doesn't work for me because the text will overflow from the whole table width.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you maybe looking for the `\mutlicolumn` macro?

Comment: `\small Sep 2018 - Feb 2023` not `\small{Sep 2018 - Feb 2023}` (although it makes no difference here)

Comment: You surely get a syntax error for `{\raggedleft\arraybackslash} p{.1\textwidth}`  perhaps you had `>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash} p{.1\textwidth}` But it always helps if you post complete small document producing the output shown.

Comment: Sorry, I did get a syntax error, but because overleaf just compiled the code anyway, I ignored it. Thank you, Will provide the complete code next time.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thank you very much, I looked it up and learned a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wrap the text on the right side of the table, this code uses two columns: the first with a fixed width, and the second an X column.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[left=3.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm, showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\small}p{.2\textwidth} X@{}}
    
Sep 2022 - Jan 2023     &
\large\textbf{Teaching Assistant, Cloud Computing}\hfill\small Random Univ. of Tech. \\
                        & Under the supervision of Dr. Random \\
                        &   \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3in, topsep=0pt]
                                \item Did this super important thing did this super important thing did this super important thing did this super important thing 
                                \item Worked on that research paper          
                            \end{itemize}    \\

Sep 2018 - Feb 2023     &
\large\textbf{Teaching Assistant, Machine Learning}\hfill\small Random Univ. of Tech.  \\
                        & Under the supervision of Dr. Random \\
                        &   \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3in, topsep=0pt]
                                \item Did this super important thing
                                \item Worked on that research paper          
                            \end{itemize}        \\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Using the `enumitem` package you can set global configurations for lists. For example, to get a compact list use

```
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=6ex,noitemsep, nosep}
```

Comment: Thank you. For anyone interested in the future, I also tried the approach with `\multirow` and `\multicolumn`. Note that `\multicolumn` cells don't offer text-wrapping by default, and to do so, you have to somehow specify a max width, either by setting a number, or estimating the size of the columns by its content in code. While there were examples of that approach on TeX.SX, they are a bit more difficult than the solution here.